# Rails 5: Create Multiple Join Table Items via Multiple Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm using a `has_many through:` relationship to classify `blogs` into `subcategories` via `blog_categorizations`.

I have all the models set up properly:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blog_categorizations
  has_many :subcategories, through: :blog_categorizations
end

class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blog_categorizations
  has_many :blogs, through: :blog_categorizations
end

class BlogCategorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

But now I'm having trouble getting it set up in my `blogs/_form`.  I have the following multiple select:

```
<select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary md-form" multiple searchable="Search here...">
  <%= Subcategory.all.each do |sub| %>
    <option value="<%= sub.id %>"><%= sub.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
<label class="mdb-main-label">Subcategories</label>
```

Which properly renders the list of possible subcategories, but now I can't figure out how to create a new `blog_categorization` for each one that is selected.  I want to use a `hidden_field` but I feel like that's not right in this instance.

Has anyone implemented something like this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the form helper of Simple Form to create select. Input's id is important. It should be `subcategory_ids`

   ```
   <%= f.input :subcategory_ids, collection: Subcategory.all,
                                 input_html: { multiple: true } %>
   ```
2. Permit subcategory_ids parameter in `BlogsController`. Add subcategory_ids (array) as the last argument to the permit method.

   ```
   def blog_params
     params.require(:blog).permit(:foo, :boo, subcategory_ids: [])
   end
   ```

Comment: But what I need is the join table...the BlogCategorization...right?  Isn't this cutting out the middle man?

Comment: @Liz You should not create record for join table (BlogCategorization). Rails already managing it in the has_many through relationship.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  However, when I use the `f.input` you suggested the only thing visible is the label...it doesn't actually show a form item at all.

Comment: Even with an extra column added to my blogs table (and of course `:subcategory_ids: []` added to my permit parameters, `subcategory_ids` is still coming up as an unpermitted parameter and not saving...

Comment: @Liz You should not create subcategory_ids field. Can you share blog form and blog_params method?

Comment: @Liz it would be great if you shared what worked... that's kinda the point of stackoverflow

Comment: I think what is probably meant above in @demir's solution is not `f.input` but `f.select` which will generate a select box with multiple options available.